# 404 when accessing Jersey app in Tomcat 7

Tags: java, rest, tomcat, jersey

I am a newby in web development and I am struggling to create a simple rest web service using jersey, packed as an independent war file, to be deployed on tomcat 7.

[I have followed this tutorial](http://www-inf.it-sudparis.eu/~nguyen_n/teaching_assistant/web_services/jersey_helloworld) in order to create simple hello world restful web service.
I have used intelij in order to create the war file (both war file and exploded version of it) and deployed them on the tomcat\webapps folder.

When starting up the tomcat, I fail to access the url (`http://localhost:8080/rest/hello`)  - getting 404.

Looking at the tomcat's logs, I can't find any exception or error, other then these next set of lines:

```
INFO: Scanning for root resource and provider classes in the packages:
  sample
εαΘ 30, 2013 11:24:38 PM com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig logClasses
INFO: Root resource classes found:
  class sample.Hello
εαΘ 30, 2013 11:24:38 PM com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig init
INFO: No provider classes found.
```

I have searched it a lot and tried to follow all solutions for this error but nothing worked.

I have the feeling that I missing something very basic, due to my newbi'ness. 
Any ideas what to search ? what am I missing ?
it's a simple hello world app and I am exahuster and frustrated...

**Java class**

```
package sample;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("hello")
public class Hello {

  // This method is called if TEXT_PLAIN is requested
  @GET
  @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
  public String sayHelloInPlainText() {
    return "Hello world!";
  }

  // This method is called if HTML is requested
  @GET
  @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
  public String sayHelloInHtml() {
    return "<html> " + "<title>" + "Hello world!" + "</title>"
        + "<body><h1>" + "Hello world!" + "</body></h1>" + "</html> ";
  }
}
```

**web.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">

      <display-name>rest</display-name>

      <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
          <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
          <param-value>sample</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
      </servlet>

      <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
      </servlet-mapping>

    </web-app>
```

Comment: Please include the code for `Hello.java` and `web.xml` in your question. It's hard to help you without more details.

Comment: Is your WAR deployed as `rest`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is *similar* to this SO question: "[No provider classes found: when running Jersey REST example application](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15410096/131929)".

The message "No provider classes found" is fine, no need to worry about it. For the URL `http://localhost:8080/rest/hello` to work your WAR file needs to be called `rest.war`. Then `rest` becomes the context root. All the paths you define in the project's annotations are *relative to the context root*.

Comment: Thanks. Indeed that was my problem, after all. (missing URL). My war file is called 'webr4' and if used the url localhost:8080/webr4/hello it worked. Now all I am left is understand how to change to the context (?) so that it wouldn't be 'webr4'.

Comment: The easiest is to rename the WAR file.

Answer (score 3):

if you have called your project in eclipse: rest, so you should get the correct message: "Hello world!" from tomcat with the url:

```
http://localhost:8080/rest/hello.
```

If you for example have called your project: MyHello, with the code you posted the correct url should be:

```
http://localhost:8080/MyHello/hello
```

(The reason is that Eclipse create by default a war called as the name of the project and publish it to the tomcat server you have added in your configuration)

Let me know

Comment: Thanks. Indeed this was the problem. it worked well when changed, as I commented on the answer above.