# No provider classes found: when running Jersey REST service

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jax-rs

I am very new to Java, and i have followed a tutorial to create an JAX-RS service, everything i did was according to the tutorial, but cannot get it to work. I have attached the screen shot and logs.

[image]

**WEB.XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
  <display-name>com.duo.test</display-name>
 <servlet>
      <servlet-name>Jersey Rest Service</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
      <init-param>
          <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
          <param-value>com.duo.test</param-value>
      </init-param>
      <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>Jersey Rest Service</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>  
</web-app>
```

**MY class:**

```
package com.duo.test.status;
import javax.ws.rs.*;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("/v1/status/*")
public class V1_status {
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
    public String returnTitle()
    {
    return "<p> Java Web Serbice</p>";  
    }

}
```

**Logs:**

```
Sep 23, 2014 12:22:56 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x64;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\;D:\ndk;C:\ant\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07\bin;D:\Softwares\Ecclipse\Ecclipse\sdk\build-tools\18.1.0;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\GtkSharp\2.12\bin;C:\Takipi\lib;C:\Takipi\lib32;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\;JAVA_HOME%\bin;C:\apache-ant-1.9.4\bin;C:\adt-bundle\sdk\platform-tools;C:\adt-bundle\sdk\tools;;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_39\bin;C:\Users\sajeetharan.DUOSL.000\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\tools;C:\Users\sajeetharan.DUOSL.000\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x64;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\;D:\ndk;C:\ant\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07\bin;D:\Softwares\Ecclipse\Ecclipse\sdk\build-tools\18.1.0;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\GtkSharp\2.12\bin;C:\Takipi\lib;C:\Takipi\lib32;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\;JAVA_HOME%\bin;C:\apache-ant-1.9.4\bin;C:\adt-bundle\sdk\platform-tools;C:\adt-bundle\sdk\tools;;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_39\bin;C:\Users\sajeetharan.DUOSL.000\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\tools;C:\Users\sajeetharan.DUOSL.000\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\\tools;C:\apache-ant-1.9.4\bin;C:\adt-bundle\sdk\tools;C:\adt-bundle\sdk\platform-tools;c:\users\sajeetharan.DUOSL.000\AppData\Roaming\npm\;.
Sep 23, 2014 12:22:57 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:com.duo.test' did not find a matching property.
Sep 23, 2014 12:22:57 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Sep 23, 2014 12:22:57 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Sep 23, 2014 12:22:57 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Sep 23, 2014 12:22:57 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Sep 23, 2014 12:22:57 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 2349 ms
Sep 23, 2014 12:22:58 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Sep 23, 2014 12:22:58 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.12
Sep 23, 2014 12:23:01 PM com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig init
INFO: Scanning for root resource and provider classes in the packages:
  com.duo.test
Sep 23, 2014 12:23:01 PM com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig logClasses
INFO: Root resource classes found:
  class com.duo.test.status.V1_status
Sep 23, 2014 12:23:01 PM com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig init
INFO: No provider classes found.
Sep 23, 2014 12:23:01 PM com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl _initiate
INFO: Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.17 01/17/2013 03:31 PM'
[2014-09-23 12:23:03 TAKIPI] User code detected.
Sep 23, 2014 12:23:04 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Sep 23, 2014 12:23:04 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Sep 23, 2014 12:23:04 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 6653 ms
```

**OUTPUT:**
[image]

Comment: Have a look at this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15410096/no-provider-classes-found-when-running-jersey-rest-example-application

Comment: replace @Path("/v1/status/*") with @Path("/v1/status/")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the issue, I found with error

```
com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig init INFO: No provider classes found.
```

is using Lambda expressions(Java 8) in Rest service class.
Jersey fails to scan the annotations, if Lambdas are used in the package specified in web.xml file below:

```
  <init-param>
      <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
      <param-value>com.duo.test</param-value>
  </init-param>
```

Solution for this problem is to remove Lambda in any class in the package specified.

**NOTE:** This may be only a problem with Jersey 1.x, I have not tried using Jersey 2.x yet. Removing Lambda has helped me work around the issue temporarily.

Answer (score 3):

URL Mapping was wrong, it should be

```
<servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>Jersey Rest Service</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/v1/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

And acording to your configurations, API URL should be `http://localhost:8080/v1/status/`

Or

Change your URI Mapping in in Service class like

```
package com.duo.test.status;
import javax.ws.rs.*;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("/api/*")
public class V1_status {
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
    @Path("/v1/status/")
    public String returnTitle()
    {
    return "<p> Java Web Serbice</p>";  
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems when I ran into this it was upgrading jersey from 1.0.2 to 1.1x and the logs would say

```
INFO: Root resource classes found:
  class org.x.y.MyClass
No provider classes found.
```

And then everything would be a 404, even though it says that the webapp successfully deployed, couldn't get to it at all.

Turns out that my

```
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>Webapp Human name</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

in `web.xml` is no longer good enough for the new version of jersey, it needs to be

`<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>`

ref: http://jersey.576304.n2.nabble.com/Jersey-and-url-pattern-td4548025.html

Comment: "/" doesn't work and needs to be "/" ?! I didn't get it.

Comment: @w35l3y oops, that should be `/*` updated it, thanks for the tip.